# What is the use case of subsites in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, sub-site, hub-site

Instead of subsites, Microsoft recommends having independent site collections and commencing them via hub site. One of core reasons for this seems to be the fact that a sub site by default inherits permissions from site collection site and it becomes difficult to manage this/other requirements of breaking inheritance.

So then what exactly is the use case of sub sites?

Comment: Sub sites were used in SharePoint server (on-premises) when hub site concept was not introduced by Microsoft. Previously subsites were used for grouping multiple related sub sites under one site collection. Example: One site collection (site) for "HR" department and multiple subsites under this site collection for "Recruitment" department, "HR Trainings" department, "Employee Onboarding" department, etc. Check this if it helps: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/subsites-vs-sites/m-p/207925?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224.

Comment: In this case any member of top level site will automatically have access to all sub sites. This is different to hub site concept wherein there is no such inheritence, correct?

Comment: If you subsites inherits permissions from site collection, then YES. There is option to break permissions on subsites as well to stop inheriting permissions from parent site.

Comment: Sites associated with a SharePoint hub site don't inherit the permissions of the hub site by default. Hub owners can enable [hub site permissions sync](https://support.microsoft.com/office/set-up-your-sharepoint-hub-site-e2daed64-658c-4462-aeaf-7d1a92eba098?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) to push hub visitors (Read permissions) to associated sites. Check [SharePoint Hub site security](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/what-is-a-sharepoint-hub-site-fe26ae84-14b7-45b6-a6d1-948b3966427f#bkmk_hubsitesecurity?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, Sub sites were used in SharePoint server (on-premises) versions when hub site concept was not introduced by Microsoft.

Subsites were used for grouping multiple related "sub sites" under one site collection (site) for administration purposes (permissions, shared content types, SharePoint groups, etc.).

**Example**: One site collection (site) for "HR" department and multiple subsites under this site collection for "Recruitment" department, "HR Trainings" department, "Employee Onboarding" department, etc.

Check this if it helps: [Subsites vs sites](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/subsites-vs-sites/m-p/207925?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

If you are more concerned about permissions, here is some information which might help you:

1. If your subsites inherits permissions from site collection, any member of top level site will automatically have access to all sub sites. However, there is an option to break permissions on subsites as well to stop inheriting permissions from parent site.
2. For hub sites: Sites associated with a SharePoint hub site don't inherit the permissions of the hub site by default. Hub owners can enable [hub site permissions sync](https://support.microsoft.com/office/set-up-your-sharepoint-hub-site-e2daed64-658c-4462-aeaf-7d1a92eba098?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) to push hub visitors (Read permissions) to associated sites. Check [SharePoint Hub site security](https://support.microsoft.com/office/what-is-a-sharepoint-hub-site-fe26ae84-14b7-45b6-a6d1-948b3966427f#bkmk_hubsitesecurity?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

---

In SharePoint Online, Microsoft recommends using hub sites and flat-structure for your sites instead of using subsites.

You can find more information about why and how at:

1. [Introduction to SharePoint information architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/information-architecture-modern-experience?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [Planning your SharePoint hub sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: In subsites, what is way to break inheritence so that users added to parent site collection site do not automatically have permission to subsite?

Comment: When you are creating a new subsite, you get options to not inherit permissions from parent site and create new groups for your subsite. But, if you have already created subsite, go to site permissions page on subsite, you will see stop inheriting permissions option in top ribbon. You can remove parent site groups from permissions and use new groups for your subsite. Let me know if it clarifies your doubt else will try to post some screenshots when I will open my laptop next time (commenting via mobile phone).